# Implementing Tree Structure in disk memory

Tags: data-structures, tree, disk, b-tree, red-black-tree

I am writing some data to a text file(stored in disk) as output from my program. I want to organize the data in the text file in a search tree format so that it facilitates efficient search and replace(through the program itself). I would like to know how to implement the tree structure to be stored in a disk memory.

Comment: which language are you working in?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you hoping to modify a text file in-place? Can you show us an example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JimMischel I am trying to understand the practical application of search trees. Just would like to know how to implement a tree structure that can be pushed back and forth between RAM and disk memory. (Correct me if my understanding of the approach is wrong).

Answer (score 3):

One of the main practical difficulties of using a tree data-structure on disk is that with naive binary trees data will be "far apart" and trying to access this data will likely cause [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29) as your hard drive attempts to continuously access different locations on disk.

The classic solution to this problem is to use [B-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). The basic idea behind B-trees is that reads from disk are expensive so you should use them as little as possible. This is accomplished by using large nodes; instead of storing only two children, B-trees can have *m* children. This greatly increases the entropy of each node meaning that it takes far fewer reads to access you data.

Some more reading on B-trees can be found [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec24-B-trees/B-trees.htm), the pictures are particularly helpful in my opinion, and several implementations on B-trees can be found [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB).